# Concatenate 2 columns in KENDO grid using client template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-clienttemplate

I have my column bind on the grid as follows:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.LastName)
     .ClientTemplate($"#=IsSpecialPerson ? 'Special Message' : ''##=LastName#")
```

And now I have to add middle name with a space to the last name column if exists.
I have tried the following, but no luck.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.LastName)
   .ClientTemplate($"#=IsSpecialPerson ? 'Special Message' : ''##=LastName# ##= MiddleName != null ? MiddleName : ''#")
```

I am getting invalid template error on the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to check your template is to count the number of #'s. It should be an even number. If I write your template over separate lines it is easier to see where the problem is:

```
#=IsSpecialPerson ? 'Special Message' : ''#
#=LastName#
##= MiddleName != null ? MiddleName : ''#  // You have 3 #'s here
```

May I suggest this:

```
#=IsSpecialPerson ? 'Special Message' : ''#
#=LastName#
#if (data.MiddleName != null) {#  // I forget if the data prefix is needed here or not
    &nbsp;
    #=MiddleName#
#}#
```

Put that all into one line and it should give you the result you are looking for.